# how to throw an error once inside a callback function being triggered in a loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, callback, throw

I need to loop over a set of objects and check for a value inside a callback function. My problem is, if the value is not found, I need to throw a single error, so this needs to be outside of the callback and loop.

Right now I have this:

```
for (i = 0; i < response._conflicts.length; i += 1){
    del_rev = response._conflicts[i];
        // retrieve a document
        that.addJob( 
            "get",
            someID,
            options,
            // callback
            function (response) {
                if (condition 1) {
                    if (condition 2){
                        console.log("gotcha");
                        // run a function                    
                        f.removeDocument(someID+x);
                        return;
                    }
                } 
            },
            function (err) {
                that.error({ "status": 123 });
            }
        );
    } // end of loop

    // now if the loop turns out no results, I need to throw this error
    that.error({ "status": 404 });
    return;
```

My problem is, the second `404` error triggers before my callback check can detect if the conditions are met or not, so I'm always ending up with a `404` and second function triggering, once the conditions are met and my `f.removeDocument(someID+x)` triggers.

I have tried removing `f.removeDocument(someID+x)` from the callback and loop and only setting a variable to true/false and then throwing my error or calling my function. However, same result = the variable is false and throws the error before it's set to true in the callback.

I guess I need to put my `404` error inside the loop and inside the callback, but I don't know how I can ensure it only fires ONCE when the loop is done and conditions have not been met.

**Question**:
How can I throw an error ONCE inside a callback function, which is triggered in a loop?

Comment: `addJob()` is an asynchronous AJAX call, I suppose..?

Comment: @inhan: yes and I can't change it.

Comment: Then you're aware that the loop is already finished when you get any response, right?

Comment: I think this is the problem. The loop is done and I'm throwing my 404 BEFORE I get the response from the AJAX call and try to check for conditions.

Comment: I'm now trying to set a variable to true, if the condition in the callback is met and "if FALSE and the I'm on the last iteration, I throw the error inside the callback". let's see if this works

Comment: Use two variables in the outer scope: a counter that gets incremented each time an Ajax job finishes and a boolean that logs if any Ajax call has been successful. With every Ajax resolution, check if the counter is at a threshold value (i.e., `response._conflicts.length`), and if so, check if the success boolean has ever been set to `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an asynchronicity problem. To handle the callback as a kind of join operation you will need to wait for the last callback. A pattern like this might help:

```
var join = (function(n, fn) {
  return function() {
    if(--n === 0) {
      fn();
    }
  }
}) (response._conflicts.length, function() {
  // Check the conditions
});
```

The join function will count down the required number of times and then allow you to perform the rest of the checking after the last call has completed. You will need to trigger `join()` in your request callback.